# ERROR EN TRIGGER SQL POR VERSION MARIADB

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mariadb

He insertado este `trigger`:

```
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER tr_updStockIngreso AFTER 
    INSERT ON detalle_ingreso
     FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     UPDATE producto SET STOCK_PRODUCTO = STOCK_PRODUCTO + NEW.CANTIDAD_INGRESO 
     WHERE producto.ID_PRODUCTO = NEW.ID_PRODUCTO;
    END
    //

DELIMITER ;
```

pero recibo este error :

> 1235 - Esta versión de MariaDB no soporta todavia 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que no existan más triggers en la tabla

```
tr_updStockIngreso
```

Si no existen más triggers, asegúrate de que, si estás actualizando un trigger existente, hagas un drop primero.

En caso de que necesites dos triggers simultáneamente en el AFTER INSERT, deberás combinarlos en uno sólo.